# Pino: default level undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm very new to backend web dev and I'm trying to set up a TypeScript project. Most everything else seems fine but when I try to use the `Pino` logger, I get this error in the compiled `levels.js` file:

`` throw Error(`default level:${defaultLevel} must be included in custom levels`) ``

My `logger.ts` looks like this:

```
1 import pino from 'pino';
2 
3 const l = pino({
4   name: process.env.APP_ID,
5   level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
6 });
7 
8 export default l;
```

The project was bootstrapped via `yeoman`.

Not sure if that's enough to debug the issue.

Comment: What is `process.env.LOG_LEVEL` set to?

Comment: It's undefined. Which is probably the issue but this was all set up through yeoman, I assumed the base app would be functional.

Comment: Not sure, I've never used yeoman before, though if it's `undefined` it should just use the default value which is `info` so that's probably not the issue. Explicitly setting `undefined` in an object is the same as just not including a key.

Comment: Ok. So if I hardcode the APP_ID and LOG_LEVEL to the app name and "debug" respectively. That works. Also if I set up a fresh project with yeoman, it works right away. This current project was pulled from a git repo so I guess it put those variable values in some other location or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel dumb. The issue was that the generator didn't create a `.env`; where all those variables should have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set **incorrect value for LOG_LEVEL**:

```
LOG_LEVEL=error # error | debug | info
```

as a result `pino.level === 'error # error | debug | info'`

So to solve the issue just set up correct values, for my case:

```
LOG_LEVEL=error
```